# SDWebImage in iOS Today Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I'm writing an iOS Today Extension that has some `UIImageView`s in it. I want to set images from an url in them and so I thought using `SDWebImage` would be best. I wrote the code below:

```
#import "TodayViewController.h"
#import <NotificationCenter/NotificationCenter.h>
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "SDImageCache.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.m"
#import "SDImageCache.m"

@interface TodayViewController () <NCWidgetProviding>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *firstImage;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *titleLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *dataOne;

@end

@implementation TodayViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [self updateData];

    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 230);

    NSInteger quarterSize = self.view.frame.size.width/4;
    NSInteger eightSize = quarterSize/4;

    self.firstImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(eightSize, 45, quarterSize, quarterSize*1.25)];
    [self.firstImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://anluan.com/crest2.jpg"]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.firstImage];

    self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(eightSize, self.firstArticle.frame.origin.y + self.firstArticle.frame.size.height + 10, quarterSize, 20)];
    self.titleLabel.text = [self.dataOne objectForKey:@"title"];
    self.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13];
    [self.titleLabel sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:self.titleLabel];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(userDefaultsDidChange:)
                                                 name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)defaultMarginInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

    // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResultFailed
    // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResultNoData
    // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResultNewData

    completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
}

- (void)userDefaultsDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self updateNumberLabelText];
}

- (void)updateNumberLabelText {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.company.TodayExtensionDefaults"];
    self.dataOne = [defaults objectForKey:@"dataOne"];
    }
}

@end
```

However, this keeps crashing, throwing this error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a88cc30'`

Comment: I have setup a test project and I have added the SDWebImage and it's working perfectly fine. I can see the image from the given url.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove following:

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.m"
#import "SDImageCache.m"
```

You never have to import implementation lines, only headers. In general principle of OOP you should hide implementation from other classes, thats called encapsulation.

Second, import #import `<SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>`

That file have declaration of your `setImageWithUrl` method.

Cheers.

Comment: Do you have file #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
? It shouldn't throw an exception if u have it, because that class have declaration of your method.

Comment: Yeah, I have that. Can't it have something to do with the fact that this is a Today View extension?

Comment: @user4486205 i think the problem is, you somehow didn't include SDWebImage library in your project properly. It have nothing to do with your controller, it simply tell you that application could not find method with such name. If you command click on #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
 you will find that method you wish to call. My advise - remove SDWeb image and include AFNetworking. Thats  better then digging in your code, after 10 mins you will have similar method working (if you include AFNetworking library correctly).